# Magento extension installation order

Tags: extensions, install, installation

I was wondering if there is a mechanism to set the order of Magento extension installations. I created a custom module which has an install script. That install script checks default's store category, but the problem is that Magento tries to install this custom extension before Catalog. Is there a way to set the installation order? I tried with `<depends><Mage_Catalog/><Mage_Core/></depends>` in extension xml file but that didn't work.
One option is to install clean Magento first, and then my custom extension by setting `<active>true</active>`, but I would like to make it automatically.
Thanks...

Comment: Another solution is to make it in a data-upgrade script.

Answer (score 3):

Keep `<depends><Mage_Catalog/><Mage_Core/></depends>` in extension definition xml.

Also move your checks default's store category into `install-upgrade` script. Which should be run after install scripts.

Also you can read [this article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/) about `install`, `install-upgrade`, `data` and `data-upgrade` scripts.